# Why could '-XX:+UseLWPSynchronization' negatively impact stamplock on Windows OS?

Tags: java, jvm, synchronization, performance-testing, jmh

I would like to implement a simple rate limiter in java to learn how to use jmh. A simple github project is created at 'https://github.com/William1104/rate-limiter'

Interestingly, the throughput of some implementations (with stamplock) are impacted when '-XX:+UseLWPSynchronization' option is enabled. The benchmark test was performed on a Windows machine and I expect it has no impact to non-Solaris system. However, the testing result showing differently. May I know anyone may help me to understand what happen exactly?

Here are testing result on my machine as a reference:

With option:  `-server, -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions, -XX:+UseNUMA`

| Benchmark | (rateLimiterType) | Mode | Cnt | Score | Error | Units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_1 | StampLockLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 21487.385 | ▒ 1082.163 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_1 | StampLockInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 13162.330 | ▒ 1585.555 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_1 | SynchronizedLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 15362.934 | ▒ 227.704 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_1 | SynchronizedInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 17281.675 | ▒ 2148.057 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_10 | StampLockLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 6868.653 | ▒ 146.372 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_10 | StampLockInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 8189.747 | ▒ 335.517 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_10 | SynchronizedLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 6643.004 | ▒ 103.568 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_10 | SynchronizedInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 5252.975 | ▒ 190.363 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_100 | StampLockLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 7352.890 | ▒ 2109.446 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_100 | StampLockInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 8675.814 | ▒ 922.653 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_100 | SynchronizedLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 6509.368 | ▒ 157.212 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_100 | SynchronizedInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 5042.867 | ▒ 192.971 | ops/ms |

With option:  `-server, -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions, -XX:+UseNUMA, -XX:+UseLWPSynchronization`

| Benchmark | (rateLimiterType) | Mode | Cnt | Score | Error | Units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_1 | StampLockLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 11383.198 | ▒ 353.921 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_1 | StampLockInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 11666.918 | ▒ 842.426 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_1 | SynchronizedLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 15696.852 | ▒ 371.078 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_1 | SynchronizedInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 15357.617 | ▒ 650.846 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_10 | StampLockLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 6937.050 | ▒ 130.727 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_10 | StampLockInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 8268.909 | ▒ 291.471 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_10 | SynchronizedLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 9134.319 | ▒ 1208.998 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_10 | SynchronizedInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 5294.341 | ▒ 225.995 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_100 | StampLockLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 8453.825 | ▒ 1075.312 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_100 | StampLockInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 16297.921 | ▒ 611.255 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_100 | SynchronizedLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 12536.378 | ▒ 974.951 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_100 | SynchronizedInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 9051.560 | ▒ 1303.856 | ops/ms |

There are the implementation of StampLockLongArrayRateLimiter and SynchronizedLongArrayRateLImiter:

```
package one.williamwong.ratelimiter;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.StampedLock;

public class StampLockLongArrayRateLimiter implements IRateLimiter {

    private final long duration;
    private final long[] records;
    private final StampedLock lock;
    private int pointer;

    public StampLockLongArrayRateLimiter(int maxInvokes, Duration duration) {
        this.duration = duration.toNanos();
        this.records = new long[maxInvokes];
        this.lock = new StampedLock();
        this.pointer = 0;
    }

    @Override public void acquire() {
        final long stamp = lock.writeLock();
        try {
            final long now = System.nanoTime();
            if (records[pointer] != 0) {
                final long awayFromHead = now - records[pointer];
                if (awayFromHead < duration) {
                    handleExcessLimit(records.length, Duration.ofNanos(awayFromHead));
                }
            }
            records[pointer] = now;
            pointer = (pointer + 1) % records.length;
        } finally {
            lock.unlockWrite(stamp);
        }
    }

    @Override public void reset() {
        final long stamp = lock.writeLock();
        try {
            Arrays.fill(records, 0);
            this.pointer = 0;
        } finally {
            lock.unlockWrite(stamp);
        }
    }

}
```

```
package one.williamwong.ratelimiter;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SynchronizedLongArrayRateLimiter implements IRateLimiter {

    private final long duration;
    private final long[] records;
    private final Object lock;
    private int pointer;

    public SynchronizedLongArrayRateLimiter(int maxInvokes, Duration duration) {
        this.duration = duration.toNanos();
        this.records = new long[maxInvokes];
        this.lock = new Object();
        this.pointer = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void acquire() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            final long now = System.nanoTime();
            if (records[pointer] != 0) {
                final long awayFromHead = now - records[pointer];
                if (awayFromHead < duration) {
                    handleExcessLimit(records.length, Duration.ofNanos(awayFromHead));
                }
            }
            records[pointer] = now;
            pointer = (pointer + 1) % records.length;
        }
    }

    @Override public void reset() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            Arrays.fill(records, 0);
            this.pointer = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: [100 millisecond](https://github.com/William1104/rate-limiter/blob/develop/src/jmh/java/one/williamwong/ratelimiter/RaterLimiterBenchmark.java#L9) measurement for running 100 threads? *('This is fine' meme)*

Comment: `-XX:+UseLWPSynchronization` indeed has no effect on Windows. Both because it is not even read, and because 'true' is the default value of the flag.

Comment: Hi @apangin, thanks for your comment. I will rerun the benchmark to make sure what I observed is stable. May I know how long should the measurement should be? Any recommendation or reference? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your comment. I rerun my benchmark with a different settings. If we execute the JMH again with 1sec for each iteration, I got following result:

With option:  -server, -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions, -XX:+UseNUMA, -XX:-UseLWPSynchronization

| Benchmark | (rateLimiterType) | Mode | Cnt | Score | Error | Units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_1 | StampLockLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 23573.282 | ▒ 364.739 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_1 | StampLockInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 23062.260 | ▒ 1035.395 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_1 | SynchronizedLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 34667.411 | ▒ 246.003 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_1 | SynchronizedInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 36426.369 | ▒ 1248.360 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_10 | StampLockLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 13592.158 | ▒ 76.319 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_10 | StampLockInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 14564.306 | ▒ 474.613 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_10 | SynchronizedLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 13524.610 | ▒ 155.850 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_10 | SynchronizedInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 13080.967 | ▒ 309.736 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_100 | StampLockLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 13224.529 | ▒ 459.035 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_100 | StampLockInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 13890.278 | ▒ 456.182 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_100 | SynchronizedLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 12672.925 | ▒ 314.118 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_100 | SynchronizedInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 12245.120 | ▒ 296.395 | ops/ms |

With option:  -server, -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions, -XX:+UseNUMA, -XX:+UseLWPSynchronization

| Benchmark | (rateLimiterType) | Mode | Cnt | Score | Error | Units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_1 | StampLockLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 24842.514 | ▒ 372.521 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_1 | StampLockInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 24327.864 | ▒ 322.659 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_1 | SynchronizedLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 34490.411 | ▒ 330.288 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_1 | SynchronizedInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 38383.257 | ▒ 654.269 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_10 | StampLockLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 13536.284 | ▒ 74.613 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_10 | StampLockInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 13702.022 | ▒ 289.616 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_10 | SynchronizedLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 12530.107 | ▒ 243.471 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_10 | SynchronizedInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 10795.833 | ▒ 158.400 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_100 | StampLockLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 13204.275 | ▒ 200.937 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_100 | StampLockInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 11606.823 | ▒ 224.213 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_100 | SynchronizedLongArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 11504.124 | ▒ 107.543 | ops/ms |
| RaterLimiterBenchmark.thread_100 | SynchronizedInstantArrayRateLimiter | thrpt | 90 | 10732.451 | ▒ 118.753 | ops/ms |

I don't observe huge performance difference when 'UseLWPSynchronization' is enable or not.  The issue I got is related to unstable JMH setup.